# Closest value using Excel 2019

Tags: excel

Here is the sample data:

[image]

Here is the formula used in B5:

```
=INDEX(B1:F1,MATCH(B4,B2:F2,1))
```

So my intention is to get the year (B1:F1) which has a corresponding value (B2:F2) closest to the entered value of 12 (B4).

Given this, the result of 1928 (B5) is not correct - expecting 1930.

Using Excel 2019 (from Office Profession Plus 2019) and therefore no XLOOKUP available - (UPDATE: this was an error on my part - should have tried LOOKUP...).

*Ideally I'd like the closest match and NOT be limited to either one of the below or above value.*

I do see in the MATCH description that the "The values in the lookup_array argument must be placed in ascending order" - so not sure how to go about that if that is the issue.  If this is the case, I wasn't sure how to sort the values (B2:F2) without losing the relationship to associated year (B1:F1).

FWIW, according to the docs it should be returning #N/A since the lookup array is not in ascending order (using ,1).

Bear in mind there's a lot more data involved and this is the simplest example I could produce.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not only the order is specified  for the match() function but also the type of match using 1,-1 or 0 So you can test all of those combinations.

Comment: Lookup, vlookup and hlookup functions ARE available though.

Comment: Nope - answer in duplicate is not practical to rearrange all data.  Not too helpful to close question when people were supplying good info.

Comment: Yes - I will update title - but certainly not a reason to close question - not sure what your 2nd comment is meaning - no worries the provided answer looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
=INDEX(B1:F1,MATCH(MIN(ABS(B2:F2-B5)),ABS(B2:F2-B5),0))
```

You might need to *Ctrl+Shift+Enter* when entering formula.

Result:

[image]